# App engine NDB make_key alternative in Python SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Flask. I'm transferring an application from Google App Engine Webapp2 in which models have been implemented using NDB, so I need to convert these models into SqlAlchemy models. I found a `make_key` method in models classes which I don't know what they exactly, so how can I convert it to SqlAlchemy models.

**Here are some examples of models from `NDB`:**

```
class Groupvalue(ndb.Model):
    """A main model for representing an individual Guestbook entry."""
    value = ndb.StringProperty()
    rank = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    username = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def make_key(cls, isbn):
        return ndb.Key(cls, isbn)

class LoxonValues(ndb.Model):
    """A main model for representing an individual Guestbook entry."""
    value = ndb.StringProperty()
    score = ndb.StringProperty()
    rank = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    group = ndb.StringProperty(default='notingroup')
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_key(cls, isbn):
        return ndb.Key(cls, isbn)
```

and Here's how I have transferred these models into Python-SqlAlchemy:

```
class Groupvalue(db.Model):
    value = db.Column(db.String())
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer(default=1))
    username = db.Column(db.String())


class LoxonValues(db.Model):
    value = db.Column(db.String())
    score = db.Column(db.String())
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer(default=1))
    username = db.Column(db.String())
    group = db.Column(db.String(default='notingroup'))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

I'm confused about the `make_key` method which has been utilized into `NDB` models, what's the equivalent of this in SqlAlchemy?

Comment: Does that mean you are migrating your database to a sql based solution from ndb?

Comment: yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `make_key()` in `sqlalchemy`. Instead you mark a column as primary key.

From `nbd/key.py`

```
A key [is a]...

* a list of one or more ``(kind, id)`` pairs where ``kind`` is a string
  and ``id`` is either a string or an integer
...

The last ``(kind, id)`` pair gives the kind
and the ID of the entity that the key refers to, the others merely
specify a "parent key".

The kind is a string giving the name of the model class used to
represent the entity. In more traditional databases this would be
the table name. A model class is a Python class derived from
:class:`.Model`. Only the class name itself is used as the kind. This means
all your model classes must be uniquely named within one application. You can
override this on a per-class basis.

The ID is either a string or an integer. When the ID is a string, the
application is in control of how it assigns IDs. For example, you
could use an email address as the ID for Account entities.

...
```

A relational database is not hierarchical, i.e. no `[(kind,id),...]` key, 
but a primary key to address an entry in a flat table.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475645/sqlalchemy-one-to-one-relation-primary-as-foreign-key) has an example.

In your conversion, you seem to miss the primary and foreign key specification.